# Have any other ways to combine strings of same item?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
[image]

I would like to ask how to shorten the code below? Have any other ways to achieve the same result?

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim nRow As Integer: nRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To nRow
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) And Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i + 2, 1) And Cells(i + 2, 1) = Cells(i + 3, 1) And Cells(i + 3, 1) = Cells(i + 4, 1) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 1, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 2, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 3, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 4, 2)
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 4).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) And Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i + 2, 1) And Cells(i + 2, 1) = Cells(i + 3, 1) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 1, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 2, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 3, 2)
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 3).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) And Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i + 2, 1) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 1, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 2, 2)
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 2).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) & "/" & Cells(i + 1, 2)
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `Dictionary` object to achieve this.

Comment: Shorter code doesn't necessarily mean better code. Some good solutions to this problem will be over a similar number of lines as you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's another dictionary approach (no reference adding required)

```
Sub strings()
    Dim data As Variant, key As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    data = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(data)
            .Item(data(i, 1)) = .Item(data(i, 1)) & "/" & data(i, 2)
        Next
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).ClearContents

        i = 1
        For Each key In .Keys
            i = i + 1
            Cells(i, 1) = key
            Cells(i, 2) = Mid(.Item(key), 2)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

*BTW*, should you *ever* need to combine strings from more columns, you could use

```
Option Explicit

Sub strings()
    Dim data As Variant, key As Variant
    Dim i As Long, iCol As Long

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            data = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For iCol = 2 To UBound(data, 2)
            For i = 1 To UBound(data)
                .Item(data(i, 1)) = Trim(.Item(data(i, 1)) & " " & data(i, iCol))
            Next
            Range("A2").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
            Range("A2").Resize(.Count).Offset(, iCol - 1) = Application.Transpose(.Items)
            .RemoveAll
        Next
    End With
    Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Replace what:=" ", replacement:="/", lookat:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Comment: @Drager I didn’t mean to steal the “accepted answer” from shrivallabha-redij. So please to chose the best answer consider only your _original_ question and not the subsequentl enhancement you added and removed right after my comment.

Comment: Your answer and shrivallabha-redij answer both meet my requirements. Your code could be used for more columns, so finally I think your answer better.

Answer (score 4):

Here's `Dictionary` based approach which should work for you.

```
Public Sub RearrangeData()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim varRng
    Dim i As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    objDic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare '\\ change this if you need it case sensitive
    varRng = Range("A2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    For i = LBound(varRng) To UBound(varRng)
        If objDic.Exists(varRng(i, 1)) Then
            objDic.Item(varRng(i, 1)) = objDic.Item(varRng(i, 1)) & "/" & varRng(i, 2)
        Else
            objDic.Add varRng(i, 1), varRng(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Range("A2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    Range("A2").Resize(objDic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(objDic.Keys)
    Range("B2").Resize(objDic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(objDic.Items)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Deleted mine as essentially the same and yours managed to post first!

Comment: And you get a +1 for Application.Transpose(objDic.Items) NIce

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thank you! this code is really great. If one more column need to join string, how to do it?

Comment: @Drager, thanks for the feedback. Please show example input and output by editing question.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij The example like the picture showed. Thanks!

Comment: @Drager, _chamaelon_ questions are not allowed. you got a solution for one question. if you have different needs then please post a new question

Comment: @Drager Use one more dictionary object. It will be easier to manage.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, it actually suffices one dictionary object only to be cleared after each usage

Comment: @Drager, please undo your question edit to go back to your original one, otherwise this answer would not be its solution

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks for advice.

Comment: @DisplayName I was looking at the simultaneous handling of both columns!

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, but that was not your original question wording nor data example: they both were intended for one single column (column B) to be grouped by column A “keys”

Comment: @DisplayName I am not sure you've read all of OP's comment posts on my answer. OP has clearly said `@shrivallabha.redij Thank you! this code is really great. If one more column need to join string, how to do it?`. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, yes I read that comment precisely. And it was changing the question you already answered. That’s why I asked him to take the new issue to another post while leaving this question in its original wording